# Can ZamZam water improve a person at a neurological level?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, umrah

Salamo3alaykom, I've a question regarding ZamZam water. I've read a hadeeth stating that ZamZam water is for whatever is drunk for, but this to which extent and how much of it should I drink? For example me I've always been stubborn and often I find it quite difficult to understand some concepts, can ZamZam water improve a person at a neurological level or make the person very intelligent if the person wishes so?

Answer (score 1):

The hadith you refer to is qualified as  weak (see for example [here](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=1636&idto=1636&bk_no=74&ID=681) the doubt expressed by al-Hakim from Nishapur about one narrator who basically is truthful) or fabricated by some scholars others consider it sahih, but maybe the most correct view is that it reaches the level of hassan (due to the sum of narrations and reports containing similar information) and is for example mentioned in [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1331790):

> “I heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say: ‘The water of Zamzam is for whatever it is drunk for.’”

Most of the narrations

And the prophet() also described it as:

> It is blessed (water) and it also serves as food. (in this long hadith in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/44/189))

As for the benefits or the interpretation of the (first) hadith we can only rely on what we know or hear:

- Among the first who considered this hadith as sahih was the scholar [Sufyan ibn 'Uyaynah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufyan_ibn_%60Uyaynah): Who when asked whether he would qualify this hadith as true answered: Yes. The asker than said I've recently drunk it with the intention to hear hundered hadith from you. And ibn 'Uyaynah did so (Source [this](https://ar.islamway.net/fatwa/31002/%D9%87%D9%84-%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AB-%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%A1-%D8%B2%D9%85%D8%B2%D9%85-%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A7-%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A8-%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%B5%D8%AD%D9%8A%D8%AD-%D9%88%D9%87%D9%84-%D9%8A%D8%AC%D9%88%D8%B2-%D9%86%D9%82%D9%84%D9%87-%D9%85%D9%86-%D9%85%D9%83%D8%A9) fatwa -in Arabic- on islamway). This story was narrated by ad-Dynawri [الدينوري](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%88_%D8%A8%D9%83%D8%B1_%D8%A3%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%8A) in his al-Mujalasah المجالسة وجواهر العلم (see also fatwa islamqa #[1698](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/1698/virtues-and-characteristics-of-the-water-of-zamzam)).
- In the fatwa above you may also read:

  > Al-‘Allaamah al-Abbi (may Allaah have mercy on him) said:
  >   “(The water) is for whatever purpose it is drunk for, and Allaahmade it food and drink for Ismaa’eel and his mother Haajar.”

  and

  > Ibn al-Mubaarak entered Zamzam and said, “O Allaah, Ibnal-Mu’ammal told me, from Abu’l-Zubayr from Jaabir that the Messenger of Allaah(peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: ‘The water of Zamzam is forwhatever purpose it is drunk for,’ so, O Allaah, I am drinking it (to quench) mythirst on the Day of Resurrection.”
- Imam [as-Suyuti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Suyuti) has been said to have drunk from it with the intention to reach a level of fiqh like that of Siraj ad-Dyn al-Balqini [سراج الدين البلقيني](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B3%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AC_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%84%D9%82%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8A) (who was a teacher of ibn Hajar and the father of as-Suyuti's teacher 'Alamu a-d-Dyn) and in hadith-sciences of [ibn Hajar al-'Asqalani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Hajar_al-%E2%80%98Asqalani) (Source [Arabic Wikipedia](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%AC%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%84_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%8A%D9%88%D8%B7%D9%8A)).

More references (in Arabic):

Fatwa islamweb #[110732](https://fatwa.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/110732/) discusses the authenticity of the hadith and states some experiences and [this thread](https://www.ahlalhdeeth.com/vb/showthread.php?t=2802) discusses the authenticity and sources of this hadith.

Comment: Salamo3alaykom. Thank you for the answer. Wallahi I need to drink it because I sometimes feel like a jaahil and I try my best to improve and become more intelligent and wiser. I wish I could live in Makkah and stay there. Even as a beggar. I would drink gallons if I could.

Comment: One more question. Does this hadith apply to righteous Scholars  only or ignorant and shortcomingful people as myself as well?

Comment: @user33954 try and you'll see and Allah knows best!